# Cannot read property 'collection' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my code

```js
// Retrieve
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
  if(!err) { 
     console.log('we are connected'); 
  }

  var k ='testt';
  var collection = db.collection(k);
  var doc1 = {'hello':'doc1'};
  var doc2 = {'hello':'doc2'};
  var lotsOfDocs = [{'hello':'doc3'}, {'hello':'doc4'}];

  collection.insert(doc1);

  collection.insert(doc2, {w:1}, function(err, result) {});

  collection.insert(lotsOfDocs, {w:1}, function(err, result) {});

});
```

and it is is showing this error "Cannot read property 'collection' of null".

Comment: Did you check the content of `err`?

Comment: No,how to check it? I m beginner at Node.js and was just trying to connect it to mongodb.

Comment: do this: `if (err) {console.error(err); }`

Comment: don't make nodejs code as executable in browser its futile !

Comment: Are you running the code as "node filename.js"? The above code works fine for me. I ran the code using the command "node <filename.js>". The documents are inserted successfully as well.

Comment: It worked.Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you are directly calling db.collection irrespective of whether db connection is successful or not. You need to check whether there is an error in db connection. db.collection works only when the DB connection is successful. Check below example for better understanding

```
 MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test',function(err,db){
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Connected to db");

        db.collection('testt').insert({"doc1":"hello"},function(err,data){

      if(err)
    {
      throw(err);
    }
    else
    {
     console.log("sucessfuly inserted");
    }

})
```